# cannot find module socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm pretty new to nodejs and socket.io. At the time I don't know anything about nodejs. I met a horrible error.

My whole steps to install nodejs (on Windows 7):

```
- Access nodejs.org and click to their green download button.
- Install nodejs in F:/nodejs
- Install socket.io with command npm install socket.io
- Install node supervisor with command npm install supervisor -g
```

That's all. Then I try to use socket.io with this line:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

And it output an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\nodejs\chat.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I've tried all suggested method like cleaning cache, reinstalling nodejs or changing socket.io module path. Unfortunately, all of those solutions didn't solve this problem.

This terrible error killed my whole day. I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS - How to resolve "Cannot find module" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/nodejs-how-to-resolve-cannot-find-module-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058298/error-cannot-find-module-socket-io

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to execute `npm install socket.io` in the folder where your node.js file is (where you require the module). npm creates a folder `node_modules` wherever you execute `npm install socket.io` and you probably didn't do this in the correct folder.

`npm install supervisor -g` did work because -g is the global flag and you can basically do that anywhere.

Comment: @pennstatephil yes for supervisor not socket.io though

Comment: I did your suggestion. And nothing change.

Comment: @user3247703 can you confirm you see node_modules folder in the root folder of your project with socket.io folder init?

Comment: I've checked module path with this code `console.log(module.paths)`. And this is the result `F:\\nodejs\\node_modules, F:\\node_modules`

Comment: My socket.io folder was placed in `npm app`, in windows appData folder

Comment: I forgot your first suggestion. It worked. Very very big thanks for this.

Comment: Oh, I was away for a bit to get lunch. Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: "Try to execute npm install socket.io in the folder where your node.js file is." This worked for me.
I wonder why my global command didnt work?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK the global flag is used mostly for CLI modules like grunt for example. You would normally install your project dependencies via `npm install` so your package.json gets updated for version control :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the package installed by `npm install socket.io` is not only the module itself, but also brings a sample and more stuff.

When you install, npm creates a `node_modules` folder.
Inside that folder, there is a folder named `socketio` .
Inside that one, there is another folder named `node_modules` .
Inside this one, there is a folder named `socket.io` .
Move or copy this one folder (`socket.io`) to inside the first `node_modules` folder right where your script is. Et voilla, it works!

[image: folder levels]