# Cannot find module "socket.io"

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-modules

Hi i am trying to run the nodejs script and it pops up the following error message:

[image]

I have installed `socket.io` globally using following command:

```
>npm install -g socket.io
```

but still no luck.

Any help?

Comment: Don't install it globally. Only install modules globally which you'll be using command line interfaces of, like mocha or casper. Anything you "`require`" in your app is installed locally.

Comment: i installed it locally first but it is not working either thats why i installed globally later

Comment: In your app folder there's a "node_modules" directory, does "socket.io" exists in it?

Comment: I can't think of any reason it shouldn't be working in that case :/. Try deleting the folder, clearing npm cache (`npm cache clean`) and installing it again. Also, are the other modules working fine?

Comment: Show us the `require()` line you use to load it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058298/error-cannot-find-module-socket-io

Answer (score 5):

Use it locally instead, and save to your `package.json`

```
npm install socket.io --save
```