# Cannot find module 'socket.io' after global install

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I try to use socket io so I follow they tutorial in [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).
I did:

```
 var app = require('express')();
```

And I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Before running I did in the command line:

```
npm install --save express@4.10.2
```

Like described in they tutorial.
So I search for that and I find this answer [node.js, Error: Cannot find module 'express'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949118/node-js-error-cannot-find-module-express)

So I did like the first answer:

```
 npm install express
```

And now I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'

So I search again and I found that I need to install its globaly ([Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058298/error-cannot-find-module-socket-io) first answer)

So I did:

```
 npm install -g socket.io
```

But still the same error again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install `express` or `socket.io` globally.

The error is the result of Node being unable to find the `express` module in your local `npm` registry; the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file. You need to create a `package.json` file in the root of your project.

Navigate to the root of the directory and run:

`npm init`

The command [npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) creates the `package.json` file. Any subsequent installs with the `--save` option will install the module and register it in the `package.json`.